# Help me hosting Apache server on a LAN connected computers?

Tags: web-hosting

i have build a JSP project,but i really want that other computer connected to my computer can access by website.i have never done it before Please help me.Now my server can be accessed using http://localhost:8080 on my local machine.what are the configuration i need to do please tell me.please post some link or step by step help.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention what server-software you use... Include the OS and application with all version numbers.

Comment: To find out what your IP address is, type `ipconfig` in a command window on Microsoft Windows, or `ifconfig` in a terminal windows on Linux. Others can then contact your machine on http://x.x.x.x:8080/

Answer (score 1):

Your are mentionning Apache. By default, you might have somewhere in Apache configuration (probably in httpd.conf) a line with Listen directive. It might be **Listen 127.0.0.1:8080** if you are using a package like WAMP under Windows...

Change this line to **Listen 8080**, restart Apache and have the other computer try reaching http://your.LAN.ip.address:8080 and see if it works.

If you happen to give some more details on your current setup, it might easier to assist ;)

Good luck.